# Jquery .select() for other html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

How can I leverage the same functionality of .select() but for elements other textboxes such as list elements?

Edit: To clarify, I'm not looking to retrieve the selected text, I want to make it such that a key combo will trigger the selection of a list elements for example.

Comment: have you tried on any inline elements?
doubt it will work but you can always try :P

Comment: Tried, no go. The docs are not a lie.

Comment: yeah i figured damn i'm really intrested in this I've found some plugins but they do a hole lot more then what I'm and probably you're after btw how do i add a bounty

Comment: The question has to be 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty

Comment: oh oki thx, well i've updated my answer so whatever you need it's there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well while w8ting for a good answer i found this plugin that seems to work perfectly

http://mark.koli.ch/2009/09/use-javascript-and-jquery-to-get-user-selected-text.html

if you want to do the selecting part there is another plugin
here

http://www.ryantetek.com/2010/02/selecting-text-inside-html-elements-with-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

It's not a direct approach, but you can listen for `mouseup`, then check to see if there's a selection.  It's not exactly what you asked for, but it might get you close.

[Here's an example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coltrane/EtJqP/)

Comment: That's awesome, but I'm looking to do the actual selecting, not retrieve the selected text..